# Use Cypress Variable From Command

Tags: cypress

I have a utility command in cypress:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('generateDummyText', (length: number, delay?: number) => {
  const wordLength = 5;

  const lorem = new LoremIpsum({
    wordsPerSentence: {
      max: wordLength,
      min: wordLength,
    },
    words: ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5'],
  });

  const words = lorem.generateWords(Math.ceil(length / wordLength));

  cy.wrap(words).as('dummyText');
});
```

```js
it('test', () => {
  // Generate dummy text
  cy.generateDummyText(280);

  // I want to type the "dummyText variable here"
  cy.get('myinput').type()
});
```

How can this be done? I don't need to use a custom cypress command, but I'd prefer to use one. Looking forward to your reply!

Comment: What do you want to do with this text ? You can access it simply by using `this.dummyText` eg. `cy.type(this.dummyText)`

Comment: I want to use it in cy.type(), I've updated the question, check it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it just by using:

```
cy.type(this.dummyText)
```

Another option is just to use faker to generate the random words for you.
Add the faker module to you project, then you can just do:

```
const faker = require("faker"); 

.type(faker.random.words(5));
```

instead of using a custom command for it

Comment: it worth mentioning that you can't just write `cy.generateDummyText(280);  cy.type(this.dummyText)` since the cypress commands are asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value either by alias:

```js
cy.generateDummyText(280);
cy.get("@dummyText").then(dummyText => {
   cy.get('myinput').type(this.dummyText)
})
```

or directly by the command return value:

```js
cy.generateDummyText(280).then(dummyText => {
   cy.get('myinput').type(this.dummyText)
})
```